# Currently I am working on React(Frontend Part), I have bookmark folder list, users able to select one or more bookmark files from the above list

Tags: reactjs, checkbox

**Actual UI:-**
[image: In the image, Selected bookmark files are there. how can I show checkboxes instead of that folder icon () so that user can select the check box.]
**Expecting UI:-**
[image: I Need to change the folder icon to a checkbox. I changed but it isn't working, can anyone help me?]

```
<BlockUI tag="div" blocking={foldersLoading}>
           <main id="candidates-list-container">
           {/* ref={(ref) => { mainBottom = ref; }}  */}
           <ul>
           {folders.map((folder) => {
           const folderID = folder.id;
           console.log(folderID);
           const folderName = folder.name;
           console.log(folderName);
           return (
             <li key={folderID}>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className={`job ${
                     selectedFolders.indexOf(folderID) > -1 ? 'selected' : ''
                  }`}
                  disabled={
                     bookmarkedCandidate.is_bookmarked
                     && selectedFolders.indexOf(folderID) === -1
                  }
                  onClick={() => {
                     selectFolder(folderID, folderName);
                  }}
                 >
                 <h2
                   className={`${
                      selectedFolders.indexOf(folderID) > -1 ? 'selected' : ''
                      }`}
                 >
                 <input type="checkbox" className="jss1042" value="" />
                    {folderName}
                 </h2>
               </button>
             </li>
            );
           })}
         </ul>
        </main>
        </BlockUI>
```

In the image, Selected bookmark files are there. how can I show checkboxes instead of that folder icon () so that the user can select the check box. This is my code it doesn't work for me. Please help me, guys.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to display checkboxes instead of folder icon. Well you can simply remove the button and h2 code above the checkbox code. It should cause only the checkboxes to show.

Comment: Thx for response, Suppose if I remove the button and h2 code how could I know whether the user selected which folder he selected

Comment: Give each checkbox a unique value. For example set the value of checkbox to folderID, so your checkbox code would be: `<input type="checkbox" className="jss1042" value="{folderID}" />`